# count the number of rows in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Description:**

I am adding the data in my 2D array like the following

```
my_2d_array['user1'] = {'id':name,'socket':socket};
my_2d_array['user2'] = {'id':name,'socket':socket};
```

This 2D array keeps the record of all the connected users id and their respective sockets ... 
I want to display the number of users connected .. So far to do that would be to count the number of rows in the array and display it

**I have tried following:**

```
my_2d_array[].length; // this gives nothing 
my_2d_array.length; // this outputs 0 (as number)
```

What should I do to get the number of rows

**UPDATE**

I declared my array like this

```
var my_2d_array = [];
```

Comment: how did u declare your array? as array is index based.. so can you please tell us how did u declared it .. that can help us to tell u right and exact answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could work for you

```
// initialize
var my_2d_array = {};

// add users
my_2d_array["user1"] = ...
my_2d_array["user2"] = ...

// get number of users
Object.keys(my_2d_array).length;

//=> 2
```

You should consider using `users` instead of `my_2d_array` though. It communicates better and the actual data type is an Object, not specifically an Array.

Answer (score 3):

Use `push` method

```
my_2d_array.push({'id':name,'socket':socket});
my_2d_array.push({'id':name,'socket':socket});
```

And `my_2d_array.length` to get the count

Comment: This changes the structure of his data though.

Comment: u missed the key ... if I use your method where m I supposed to save the keys e.g did u mean this my_2d_array['user1'].push(...) ??

Comment: He updated his question, and it looks like he's not meant to use hash map.

Comment: @RksRock Are you new to JavaScript? If you are, then maybe you are using the wrong variable. Seems you want a hash map, which in JS usually implemented as objects (`{}`), not array (`[]`).

Comment: @RksRock In such case @maček gave a better answer, and you'd better declare `var my_2d_array = {};`, instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to figure out how many keys are in your javascript object `my_2d_array`.

You should be able to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys)

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgd5um20/).

```
var my_2d_array = {};
var name = "Hello";
var socket = "World";
my_2d_array['user1'] = {'id':name,'socket':socket};

var name = "Hello2";
var socket = "World2";
my_2d_array['user2'] = {'id':name,'socket':socket};

alert( Object.keys(my_2d_array).length );
```